# Cannot install grunt-contrib-imagemin (weird error 1)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, gruntjs, yeoman

I cannot install the package `grunt-contrib-imagemin` in a yeoman (angular) project. It fails with

```
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

But no other errors are reported.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04, and NodeJS 0.8

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: Forgot that, updating answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solved by updating nodejs to version 0.10

I followed to instructions at http://slopjong.de/2012/10/31/how-to-install-the-latest-nodejs-in-ubuntu/